# Install MongoDb on RedHat without internet connection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, redhat, yum

Can anyone explain how to install Mongodb, pyMongo on a RedHat server without an internet connection. Although I have used both before I haave never had to install anything myself.

I have downloaded mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel62-3.0.0.tgz from [Official download page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) and copied it to the server but what do I do next?

Do I need to modify the .repo file shown in  [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/?_ga=1.23198138.1835905491.1421083456) and install with yum?

For pyMongo, pip and easy_install are not installed so I'm guessing I need to install from source. The link in the documentation, github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver.git, says "Otherwise you can download the project source and do python setup.py install to install."  Where do I get the source from ([the link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/tree) doesn't work and where do I put it on the server?

Answer (score 0):

What I did eventually (hope that helps anyone)

is that I had an access to RHEL with internet connection too (made one on google cloud).

So I modified `/etc/yum.conf` to set `keepcache=1` so packages are kept and I installed mongodb for the framework I needed there and then copied the packages from `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/server/10gen/packages`

It had meta package and four packages, for server, mongos, shell and tools

and installed the latter four, one by one with `yum install path/to/package.rpm`

and ran `service mongod start`

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Installing MongoDB on Linux machine from Binary distribution goes like this

1. Download desired binary from Mongodb official download page for your respective architecture and distro

   ```
   curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.4.tgz
   ```
2. Extract this tar ball

   ```
   tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.4.tgz
   ```
3. Make directory for mongo binary and copy them their

   ```
   mkdir -p /mongodb
   cp -R -n mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.4/ /mongodb
   ```
4. Add this path in PATH variable

   ```
   export PATH=<PATH_OF_MONGODB_BIN>:$PATH
   ```

Installing Pymongo assuming you have internet on some system to clone repo of Pymongo from Github

```
 $ git clone git://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver.git pymongo
 $ cd pymongo/
 $ python setup.py install
```

You will need atleast on machine where internet is available.